# Creating universal framework in ios in strange directory

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I followed this excellent guide on creating a framework in Xcode for iOS.

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/12/13/building-a-universal-framework-for-ios/

I have my framework, but I expected it to be under /MyProject/build/ but it's not... it's under /Users/confusedn00b/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-gsgtxxwyxrghdygelnfssplakpoc/Build

Why is that? Also, the author says 'run lipo -info ..' toward the end of the tutorial. Is he opening a terminal window to do this, or can you execute commands from xcode somehow? If the former (terminal) is it assumed he's navigating to the (crazy) folder structure above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older Xcode versions used to put all generated files in a "build" subdirectory of the project folder. (I think this is still the case if you compile from the command line with "xcodebuild".)

Current Xcode versions create all files by default in some subdirectory of "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData". A random subdirectory is used to prevent different projects with the same name from overwriting each other's data.

I prefer to have the generated files in my project folder, and fortunately you can configure that in the Xcode preferences: Go to the "Locations" tab and set "Derived Data" to "Relative" instead of "Default". Now all generated files are in the "DerivedData" subdirectory of your project folder.

To your last question: Yes, the author probably meant to run "lipo" in a Terminal, but the folder structure was "less crazy" at the time that article was written.

Comment: I added an additional run script to copy things back to a 'sensible' location: